# In JavaFx, how to use my own non-fxml custom component in the standalone Scenebuilder app?

Tags: intellij-idea, components, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I use SceneBuilder 8.3.0 and I got a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when opening an fxml file that reference my custom component.

The custom component is a full java one (without fxml to declare it) and it renders perfectly using the scenebuilder embedded with Intellij... but not in the standalone application (that works better IMO).

I tried to import it (as we can do with external jars libraries containing components), but even when specifying my own built .jar file it did do the job...